# Esper Combine Query Results

Tags: java, esper

I have an Esper query that looks as follows:

```
 @Name("MyFirstEvent")
 select a.groupID as groupdID,count(*) as result
 from pattern[every a=MyFirstEvent where timer:within(10 sec)]
 where a.value > 60
 group by a.groupID
 having count(*) >= 3
```

This appears to work fine. However, I have a requirement to take the result of this query and then combine it with the result of another query.

For example - if I see this query produce a result and then I see the other query produce a result (within 10 seconds of each other), then I want to produce a third event.

How can you do this in Esper? I tried writing a query saying: `select * from pattern[every a=MyFirstEvent -> b=MySecondEvent]` but it says that it cannot resolve MyFirstEvent to a type.

I have thought about using a named window to store the results of each query and then query the window. Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more investigation I found that the easiest way for me to do this was to:

1. Create two new windows to temporarily store the event results from my first two queries.
2. Create a third query that simply queries both of the first two windows and then joins the results together to generate a third event.